# Jenkins job for Salesforce deployment printed the -Dsf.password in console

Tags: deployment, ant, jenkins

Am using the Jenkins to do the Salesforce deployment. Build is parameterised. When I sun the ANT build for deployment, in console I could see the passport printed by the Salesforce ANT command. Is anyway to mask this password print?

Snippet of console below:

[Config_PROD_Direct_Deployment] $ /apps/dftjenkins/local/apache-ant/current/bin/ant -file build.xml -DLoginURL=https://login.salesforce.com ******** -DApexUser=user_name@company.com -Dsf.runalltests=false -Dsf.checkonly=true -Dsf.username=user_name@company.com -Dsf.maxpoll=60 -Dsf.serverurl=https://login.salesforce.com -Dsf.src=src -Dsf.pollWaitmillis=600000 -Dsf.metadataType=Document -Dsf.password=pAssw0rd -Dsf.deploy=deploy deploy2
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/tmp

Any help is appreciated to fix this. Let me know if I can share additional information.

Thanks, Manju

Comment: [Injecting Secrets into Jenkins Build Jobs](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) covers that.